# how to rotate circles only clockwise

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using HTML5 and CSS3.
I Want to rotate all the circles clockwise, when we clicked on it.
For rotating the circles, I have used only CSS.
I have added html and css for the same, all the circles are rotating on click of them, and the circle which is clicked it gets heighlighted, and displayed as white circle.

```css
/* Just for positioning the menu correctly */

#menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  top: 100px;
  left: 37px;
}
/* We're using overflow: hidden; so we need to create a fake shadow */

.faux-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  z-index: -9999;
}
/* Also change the width and height of the faux shadow */

#on-check:checked ~ .faux-shadow {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  top: -75px;
  left: -60px
}
/* So the info divs wont appear should the button be unchecked */

#menu #on-check:not(:checked) ~ .info {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* Show info sections with a delay of 0.4s to give the menu time to finish the inital
   sprawling out animation */

#menu #on-check:checked ~ .info {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0.4s;
}
/* Sprawl out the menu items when the on button is checked */

#on-check:checked ~ #menu-items {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  left: -60px;
  top: -75px;
}
/* The styling of the menu items container div */

#menu-items {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
/* I separated the pieces of the menu into two divs, top and bottom. */

#menu-items .top,
#menu-items .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50%;
}
#menu-items .bottom {
  top: 50%;
}
/* The middle div is largely to fix a bug where the content would exceed the 
   border radius when overflow: hidden; was set */

#menu-items .middle {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* The labels are what contain the icons */

#menu-items label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
/* On hover I thought they looked nice with a little blue glow! */

#menu-items label:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #a6d8f4;
}
/* The is the info boxes, these appear when the menu item is selected */

#menu .info {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -225px;
  top: -63px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #343434;
  z-index: 9999999;
  font: normal normal 1.5em Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #4aacc5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 200px;
}
.arrow-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -106px;
  left: 45px;
}
.arrow-img img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px
}
.info span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0px 5px 0 2px;
  float: left;
}
/* Hide the radio and checkboxes */

#menu input[type='checkbox'],
input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
/* Position the icons correctly */

#menu-items .top .ss-home {
  top: 90px;
  left: 34px;
}
#menu-items .top .ss-heart {
  top: 89px;
  left: 199px;
}
#menu-items .top .ss-compass {
  top: 21px;
  left: 108px;
}
#menu-items .bottom .ss-rss {
  top: 92px;
  left: 21px;
}
#menu-items .bottom .ss-star {
  top: 181px;
  left: 162px;
}
#menu-items .bottom .ss-refresh {
  top: 183px;
  left: 60px;
}
/* The below code rotates the menu items to the correct position
   when each is clicked. */

#info-home:checked ~ #menu-items,
#menu-items .top .ss-heart {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(50deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(50deg);
  transform: rotateZ(50deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
#info-heart:checked ~ #menu-items,
#menu-items .top .ss-home {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-77deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-77deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(-77deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-77deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-77deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
#info-rss:checked ~ #menu-items,
#menu-items .bottom .ss-star {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(77deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(77deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(77deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(77deg);
  transform: rotateZ(77deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
#info-star:checked ~ #menu-items,
#menu-items .bottom .ss-rss {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-148deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-148deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(-148deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(-148deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-148deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
#info-refresh:checked ~ #menu-items,
#menu-items .bottom .ss-refresh {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(145deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(145deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(145deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(145deg);
  transform: rotateZ(145deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */

#menu-items label {
  background: orange;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px #E2F724;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px #E2F724;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px #E2F724;
}
/* Highlight the selected item */

#info-home:checked ~ #menu-items .ss-home,
#info-heart:checked ~ #menu-items .ss-heart,
#info-rss:checked ~ #menu-items .ss-rss,
#info-star:checked ~ #menu-items .ss-star,
#info-refresh:checked ~ #menu-items .ss-refresh,
#info-compass:checked ~ #menu-items .ss-compass {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 5px #D3CFCF;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
/* Make opacity of the info boxes 1 when they are clicked on */

#info-home:checked ~ .home-info,
#info-heart:checked ~ .heart-info,
#info-rss:checked ~ .rss-info,
#info-star:checked ~ .star-info,
#info-refresh:checked ~ .refresh-info,
#info-compass:checked ~ .compass-info {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* ================ IGNORE ================ */

#header {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">

  <input type="checkbox" id="on-check" name="on-check" checked />

  <!--<label id="on-button" for="on-check">
 </label>-->
  <div class="arrow-img">
    <img src="images/down-arrow.png">
  </div>
  <input type="radio" id="info-compass" name="radio-check" checked />
  <input type="radio" id="info-heart" name="radio-check" />
  <input type="radio" id="info-rss" name="radio-check" />
  <input type="radio" id="info-refresh" name="radio-check" />
  <input type="radio" id="info-star" name="radio-check" />

  <div id="menu-items">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="top">
        <label class="ss-compass" for="info-compass">com</label>
        <label class="ss-heart" for="info-heart">heart</label>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <label class="ss-rss" for="info-rss">rssB</label>
        <label class="ss-refresh" for="info-refresh">refrB</label>
        <label class="ss-star" for="info-star">starB</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="info compass-info"><span></span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book. It has survived not only five centuries.</div>
  <div class="info heart-info"><span></span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book.Also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
  <div class="info rss-info"><span></span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book.</div>
  <div class="info star-info"><span></span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
    essentially unchanged.</div>
  <div class="info refresh-info"><span></span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>

  <div class="faux-shadow"></div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tbxLwwo/1/)

Comment: Please check below link.
http://sscce.org/

Comment: without javascript it isn't possible

Comment: @aleha please provide any example if you have, I am ok with the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sxfzymst/

sorry, to bad with math, so just all possible rotation shifts enumarates throu switch.

html (added onclick):

```
<input type="radio" id="info-compass" name="radio-check" onclick='rotateTo(0)' checked  />
<input type="radio" id="info-heart" name="radio-check" onclick='rotateTo(1)' />
<input type="radio" id="info-rss" name="radio-check" onclick='rotateTo(4)' />
<input type="radio" id="info-refresh" name="radio-check" onclick='rotateTo(3)' />
<input type="radio" id="info-star" name="radio-check" onclick='rotateTo(2)' />
```

css (removed cross-browser transform properties):

```
#info-star:checked ~ #menu-items, #menu-items .bottom .ss-rss { 
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
     transition: 1s ease-in;
}
```

js:

```
var currentRotatePosition = 0;
var currentDegree = 0;

function rotateTo(newPosition)
{
    var shift = 0;
    switch(currentRotatePosition)    
    {
        case 0:
            switch(newPosition)
            {
                // other cases
            }
    }
}

$('#menu-items, #menu-items .bottom .ss-refresh').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotateZ('+ currentDegree +'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotateZ('+ currentDegree +'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotateZ('+ currentDegree +'deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotateZ('+ currentDegree +'deg)',
    'transform': 'rotateZ('+ currentDegree +'deg)',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the negative degree values in rotateZ() by positive ones. Then the *first* click will rotate clockwise, because positive values rotate clockwise and negative values rotate anti-clockwise.

A negative degree can be transformed to a positive one by adding 360°, example for -77°:

```
-77° + 360° = 283°
```

So you will get following code for example:

```
#info-heart:checked ~ #menu-items, #menu-items .top .ss-home { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(283deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(283deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(283deg); 
    -o-transform: rotateZ(283deg); 
    transform: rotateZ(283deg); 
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
     transition: 1s ease-in;
}
```

Rotation of the second click depends on the degree values of the first and second selected item. If the second degree is higher than the first, rotation will be clockwise. Otherwise it will go to the other direction. For the last case I do not see a solution in CSS to rotate clockwise.

Comment: @aleha First click on all items rotates clockwise [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8tbxLwwo/2/). Second click sadly not.

Comment: @Henrik I tried your example, but it is working same as you given in example.I tried to change all the rotate degrees,but all gets messed up. :(

Comment: @Monica See my explanations in the answer. My solution only works for the first click. I think you need a JavaScript solution to handle more than one click.